# Optimise a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

For n = 18 my code takes more than 0.5s on a 1GHz machine.
I think this is due to the fact that I am using a recursive function, yet I don't really knwo how to optimise this code because it actually just "prints" numbers... 
Hence maybe the problem comes from the fact that I am using recursive function.

Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>

void singleSquareRemove (int s)
{
  if (s == 1)
    {
      std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  else
    {
      for (int i = s-1; i >=1; --i)
    singleSquareRemove(i);
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
void whenSquareisFull (int v)
{
  if (v == 1)
    {
      std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  else if (v == 2)
    {
      std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  else if (v == 3)
    {
      std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
      std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  else
    {
      whenSquareisFull(v-2);
      for (int i = v-3; i > 0; --i)
    singleSquareRemove(i);
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{

  unsigned int n {0};
  std::cin >> n;

  whenSquareisFull(n);
  for (int i = n-1; i > 0; --i)
    {
      singleSquareRemove(i);
      }

}
```

Comment: Profile, evaluate and optimize hot spots, repeat.

Comment: Normally you have to benchmark and such, but `std::endl` probably steals a lot of time.

Comment: I think it might help if you made the recursive call a tail call so that it could be optimized by the compiler.

Comment: I am willing to bet some money (not much though) that you are compiling in debug, no optimizations enabled.

Comment: Wait a sec, why are you looping AND recursing?

Comment: @Rakete1111 There's really a different time execution between '\n' and std::endl ?

Comment: @FredLarson It seems more clear to me, and I don't really know how to implement this using recursion...

Comment: That does seem exceptionally slow, are you sure it is not the fault of whatever you're trying to write to?

Comment: @Salutsalut1 printing is buffered, `endl` will flush the buffer. Always ending with `endl` will stop your buffering from working effectively.

Comment: @Salutsalut1 jup, see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/3980929

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers and my problem is actually solved because using std::endl for n = 17 takes 0.5 s while using '\n' it takes only 0.03. Next time i'll be carefull on using std::endl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time sink is when you are printing the value and flushing the output (`std::endl`).

You could avoid that time sink by using a type of "buffer", like a `std::vector` that you could then iterate over to print. In this way, the time is spent on the actual "calculations", which you can then profile, versus spending time on printing the output.

Example using your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static std::vector<int> values;

void singleSquareRemove (int s)
{
    for (int i = s - 1; i >= 1; --i)
        singleSquareRemove(i);
    values.push_back(s);
}

void whenSquareisFull (int v)
{
    switch (v) {
        case 1: case 2:
            values.push_back(v);
        break;
        case 3: {
            values.push_back(1);
            values.push_back(v);
        } break;
        default: {
            whenSquareisFull(v - 2);
            for (int i = v - 3; i > 0; --i) singleSquareRemove(i);
            values.push_back(v);
        } break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n {0};
    std::cin >> n;
    // start timing here
    whenSquareisFull(n);
    while (--n > 0) singleSquareRemove(n);
    // stop timing here
    for (auto itr = values.begin(); itr != values.end(); ++itr)
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps!